# Covering basement floor containing asbestos

Tags: flooring, asbestos, vinyl-flooring, leveling, testing

I have a house built in 1968 and in the basement the floor is covered with 12X12 vinyl tile.

I had sent the sample for asbestos testing and it came back negative for tile itself however the black mastic on the tile has 6% asbestos.

My questions are

1. What are my option to cover the floor?(I am thinking of putting floating vinyl planks) - the floor is in good condition overall except few tile which are chipped and cracked.
2. Should I paint the floor (so that it encapsulates the material) and then cover it with floating vinyl floor or some other product?
3. If I were to go for floating floor then I will face problem with slop since there is a drain in the center, how would I deal with slop for laying a floating floor?

Comment: Asbestos is very bad if you start doing stuff like sanding it, if left alone it is almost safe.  Most hard material flooring wants/needs a floor surface to be flat.  Does not need to be level, slope if floor is flat it can have a slope in one direction only.  If slope is in multiple directions, will need to use soft type flooring(carpet, vinyl) or small size hard type flooring(12x12 inch).

Comment: "Best" and "should" are opinion based. "What are my options" isn't, but it's pretty broad. "I'm considering A and B what are the pros and cons" is objective and the kind of question we can answer and is on topic here. Please [edit] your question to make it more on topic.

Answer (score 1):

The mastic is encapsulated by the tile, if there is any mastic showing paint that piece.

If you want a new floor covering that will work with the floor drain well drop the floating floor idea or add a hydroponic heating system this reduces the ceiling clearance so it’s not for everyone but it can make a nice warm difference.

I have also tiled directly over those tiles and that worked out well so there are many options but I have not had good experience with floating flooring on sloped surfaces and worse where it was wet.